# PushState without mod_rewrite

Tags: javascript, jquery, mod-rewrite

Idea:
Site has a JavaScript Navigation that toggles divs. It sends a PushState of the Divs ID (e.g. "homepage") that the URL is like domain.com/homepage. /homepage itself doesn't excist. If I reload the page, it gives a 404.


Problem:
How can I work around that and run the "changeDiv(id)" function when opening domain.com/homepage? Do I need mod_rewrite for it or can I fetch the /homepage while opening and run a Javascript function?

In case of Mod_Rewrite
If I have to use mod_rewrite, how do I do it best?
The mod_rewrite thing has to know that when I call domain.com/homepage, domain.com/javascript:changeDiv(homepage) shall run. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you do need a mod_rewrite. That or a front-controller depending on your server-side language.

Comment: `domain.com/javascript:changeDiv(homepage)` Does that actually do what you think it does?

Comment: No, it was just an example... I will just make an ?action=homepage and the PHP action controller activates the JavaScript function then...

Comment: Then what you want is one of the most common seo-friendly url rewrites. there are dozens if not hundreds of tutorials to do this specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite would be the way to go.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)$ index.php?action=$1
```

action will contain `homepage` for the following url:

```
domain.com/homepage
```

Unfortunately for me your question specifically asks for something OTHER than this, even though this is your only option.